# want java code to check the directory for incoming files, verify with the existing files and send a mail to a recipient with the file name, timestamp

Tags: java

Need Java 8 code for following scenarios:

1. Check a directory folder for incoming files.
2. If a file comes check it with the existing files in that directory.
3. If the file is new to the directory send a mail to the recipient with the file name and timestamp.

Need Java 8 code to handle all the above cases.

I mainly worked on checking the particular directory for changes in java 7 but I do not know how to check the incoming file with already existing files and send a mail.

```
package com.javapapers.java;enter code here
import java.io.IOException;enter code here
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
public class MonitorDirectory {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
Path faxFolder = Paths.get("./fax/");
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
boolean valid = true;
do {
WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
if 
(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
String fileName = event.context().toString();
System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);
}
}
valid = watchKey.reset();
} while (valid);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the file exists you can use `file.exists()` or `Files.exists(path)` if you own a *Path* to it.

To send mails, if you want to stick to Oracle, you can use [JavaMail](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html), but there are lots of another mail libs (here, for example, is the [list](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) of 3rd party ones, published at Oracle)